# Requested factory com.ctc.wstx.stax.WstxInputFactory cannot be located

Tags: java, web-services, oracle-agile-plm

I am build an Oracle Agile PLM CustomAction Px.

I called a webservice inside the Px to process some data.

After i deployed, it gave "Class not found exception" for `javax.xml.ws.Service`

so i copied `jaxws-api-2.1-1.jar` in `\Agile\Agile931\integration\sdk\extensions` folder.

After this this error was gone.

Similarly i copied some other jars to remove "Class not found exception" for other classes.

But now i dont know how to remove this error:

> Requested factory com.ctc.wstx.stax.WstxInputFactory cannot be located.  Classloader =Agile.root:0.0.0

Answer (score 7):

If you're using Maven you can add the dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.woodstox</groupId>
    <artifactId>woodstox-core</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 2):

`com.ctc.wstx.stax` refers to the Woodstox StAX parser.  You can download that [here](https://github.com/FasterXML/woodstox/releases), and add it to your classpath.