# use endorsed standard override mechanism for xerces in GlassFish 4.0

Tags: java, glassfish, java-ee-7, endorsed, xerces2-j

How do I use the [endorsed standard mechanism](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/standards/) to use xerces in a GlassFish 4.0 WAR application? According to the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1752/gchif/index.html)*, you should put it into `domain-dir/lib/endorsed`. However, when I put xercesImpl, xml-apis as well as xml-resolver there, the classes are not available from my classes in the WAR. This is most proabably due to an inconsistency between the docs and the default config: the `domain.xml` does not list `domain-dir/lib/endorsed`.

When I include it or put the files into `glassfish-install-dir/lib/endorsed`, the startup fails with the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.GlassFishMain.main(GlassFishMain.java:97)
    at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.ASMain.main(ASMain.java:54)
Caused by: A MultiException has 5 exceptions.  They are:
1. javax.xml.stream.FactoryConfigurationError: Provider com.ctc.wstx.stax.WstxOutputFactory not found
2. java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to perform operation: create on com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.DomainXmlPersistence
3. javax.xml.stream.FactoryConfigurationError: Provider com.ctc.wstx.stax.WstxInputFactory not found
4. java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: While attempting to resolve the dependencies of com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.GFDomainXml errors were found
5. java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to perform operation: resolve on com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.GFDomainXml

    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Collector.throwIfErrors(Collector.java:88)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.resolveAllDependencies(ClazzCreator.java:252)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:360)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:461)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SingletonContext$1.compute(SingletonContext.java:114)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SingletonContext$1.compute(SingletonContext.java:102)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.Cache$OriginThreadAwareFuture$1.call(Cache.java:97)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.Cache$OriginThreadAwareFuture.run(Cache.java:154)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.Cache.compute(Cache.java:199)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SingletonContext.findOrCreate(SingletonContext.java:153)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2258)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.internalGetAllServiceHandles(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:1372)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.getAllServices(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:726)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.getAllServices(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:714)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.config.ConfigurationPopulator.populateConfig(ConfigurationPopulator.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.bootstrap.HK2Populator.populateConfig(HK2Populator.java:106)
    at com.sun.enterprise.module.common_impl.AbstractModulesRegistryImpl.populateConfig(AbstractModulesRegistryImpl.java:211)
    at com.sun.enterprise.module.bootstrap.Main.createServiceLocator(Main.java:273)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.osgiadapter.HK2Main.createServiceLocator(HK2Main.java:120)
    at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.EmbeddedOSGiGlassFishRuntime.newGlassFish(EmbeddedOSGiGlassFishRuntime.java:95)
    at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.GlassFishRuntimeDecorator.newGlassFish(GlassFishRuntimeDecorator.java:68)
    at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.OSGiGlassFishRuntime.newGlassFish(OSGiGlassFishRuntime.java:91)
    at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.GlassFishMain$Launcher.launch(GlassFishMain.java:113)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: javax.xml.stream.FactoryConfigurationError: Provider com.ctc.wstx.stax.WstxOutputFactory not found
    at javax.xml.stream.XMLOutputFactory.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.DomainXmlPersistence.<init>(DomainXmlPersistence.java:85)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.reflection.ReflectionHelper.makeMe(ReflectionHelper.java:1107)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.createMe(ClazzCreator.java:274)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:368)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:461)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SingletonContext$1.compute(SingletonContext.java:114)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SingletonContext$1.compute(SingletonContext.java:102)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.Cache$OriginThreadAwareFuture$1.call(Cache.java:97)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.Cache$OriginThreadAwareFuture.run(Cache.java:154)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.Cache.compute(Cache.java:199)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SingletonContext.findOrCreate(SingletonContext.java:153)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2258)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.getService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:638)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ThreeThirtyResolver.resolve(ThreeThirtyResolver.java:77)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.resolve(ClazzCreator.java:214)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.resolveAllDependencies(ClazzCreator.java:237)
    ... 28 more
```

How do I fix this? downloading the Woodstox StAX parser into `lib/endorsed` as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6327262/requested-factory-com-ctc-wstx-stax-wstxinputfactory-cannot-be-located) did not work.

--
 * That's the documentation for GlassFish 3, but it's exactly the same in the [documentation for GlassFish 4](https://glassfish.java.net/docs/4.0/application-development-guide.pdf), which I only found as PDF

Comment: It is worth noting that the "endorsed standard override" mechanism has been dropped as of Java 9: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46419496