# How do you replace endorsed directory in Java 9?

Tags: java, java-9, endorsed

In Java 8 and prior there exists the mechanism to use an endorsed directory(java.endorsed.dirs), which is a collection of libraries which overrides JDK internal implementations.

How can I solve this in Java-9? As endorsed dirs where removed there?

Comment: You don't, you use modules instead.  Problems with endorsed and classpath is fixed with modules, becuase of several reasons.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**In JDK 9, you can use [upgradeable modules](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jigsaw/goals-reqs/03#upgradeable-modules) or put the *JAR files on the classpath.***

The [Java 9 migration guide](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/migrate/toc.htm#JSMIG-GUID-8E83E51A-88A3-4E9A-8E2A-66E1D66A966C0) states:

> The `java.endorsed.dirs` system property and the `lib/endorsed`
>   directory are no longer present. The `javac` compiler and `java`
>   launcher will exit if either one is detected.

You would end up finding the error if any of these exists as :

> ```
> <JAVA_HOME>/lib/endorsed is not supported. Endorsed standards and
> standalone APIs in modular form will be supported via the concept of
> upgradeable modules. Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
> Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
> ```

---

These endorsed-standards override mechanism was removed to attain [Modular Run-Time Images](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/220) and would now use the modular image.

> A modular image is composed of modules rather than JAR files. Going
>   forward, endorsed standards and standalone APIs are supported in
>   modular form only, via the concept of [upgradeable modules](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jigsaw/goals-reqs/03#upgradeable-modules).

Answer (score 1):

This is a specific solution but can probably be generalized. On System Version: macOS 10.14.6 (18G3020) Kernel Version: Darwin 18.7.0 I have OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 13.0.2+8, mixed mode, sharing) and java_ee_sdk-8u1 installed.

I encountered this error when executing xjc:

```
[foo@bar bin 14:47:27] sudo ./xjc
-Djava.endorsed.dirs=./../modules/endorsed is not supported. Endorsed standards and standalone APIs
in modular form will be supported via the concept of upgradeable modules.
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.enter code here
```

I edited the last line in `~/glassfish5/glassfish/bin/xjc` to remove the `-Djava.endorsed.dirs` bit:
BEFORE

```
exec "$JAVA" -Djava.endorsed.dirs="$AS_INSTALL_LIB/endorsed" -cp "$AS_INSTALL_LIB/webservices-osgi.jar:$AS_INSTALL_LIB/javax.xml.rpc-api.jar:$AS_INSTALL_LIB/jaxb-osgi.jar" com.sun.tools.xjc.Driver "$@"
```

AFTER

```
exec "$JAVA" -cp "$AS_INSTALL_LIB/webservices-osgi.jar:$AS_INSTALL_LIB/javax.xml.rpc-api.jar:$AS_INSTALL_LIB/jaxb-osgi.jar" com.sun.tools.xjc.Driver "$@"
```

After which `~/glassfish5/glassfish/bin/xjc` worked as expected

Comment: @IsanRodriguezTrimiño Hahaha!! me too!!

Comment: Hahahaha, me too, Java goes Brrrrr now.

Answer (score -4):

I also faced same issue, Java versions higher than 8 are not supported by Tomcat 9.
Please check bin/catalina.sh for more information.

> JAVA_ENDORSED_DIRS (Optional) Lists of of colon separated directories
> containing some jars in order to allow replacement of APIs
> created outside of the JCP (i.e. DOM and SAX from W3C).
> It can also be used to update the XML parser implementation.
> This is only supported for Java <= 8.
> Defaults to $CATALINA_HOME/endorsed.

Comment: "Java versions higher than 8 are not supported by Tomcat 9" This is not true, [look at the official site](https://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html). It clearly says "8 **and later**".

Comment: What is **not** supported after Java 8 is the switch  `-Djava.endorsed.dirs=...`.  It is not Tomcat that isn't supporting Java 9 and later.