# Fatal Exception while trying to run Tomcat Server in Intellij IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea, tomcat7

When i try to run Tomcat server locally i get the following error.

```
D:\aarthsoftwares\apache-tomcat-7.0.82\bin\catalina.bat run
Using CATALINA_BASE:   
"C:\Users\Aarthi\.IntelliJIdea2017.3\system\tomcat\Unnamed_messenger1"
Using CATALINA_HOME:   "D:\aarthsoftwares\apache-tomcat-7.0.82"
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: "D:\aarthsoftwares\apache-tomcat-7.0.82\temp"
Using JRE_HOME:        "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9.0.1"
Using CLASSPATH:       "D:\aarthsoftwares\apache-tomcat-
7.0.82\bin\bootstrap.jar;D:\aarthsoftwares\apache-tomcat-7.0.82\bin\tomcat-
juli.jar"
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
-Djava.endorsed.dirs=D:\aarthsoftwares\apache-tomcat-7.0.82\endorsed is not 
supported. Endorsed standards and standalone APIs
in modular form will be supported via the concept of upgradeable modules.
Disconnected from server
```

Please help with the same.

Comment: Tomcat 7 doesn't support Java 9.

Comment: @JBNizet Should i try with lower version?

Comment: If you need Java 9 support, use a version of Tomcat compatible with Java 9. If you need to use Tomcat 7, use a Java version that Tomcat 7 supports.

Comment: @JBNizet yeah thank you will try with latest version of Tomcat.

Comment: It is working now. Tomcat 9 supports java 8 and above.

Answer (score 0):

Tomcat 9 supports java 8 and above
Tomcat 8 supports java 7 and later
Tomcat 7 supports java 6
running Tomcat 9 solves the above error

Answer (score 0):

## `Endorsed` feature dropped in Java 9

Apparently you are running your Tomcat with Java 9.

Read [*JDK 9 Is the End of the Road for Some Features*](https://dzone.com/articles/jdk-9-is-the-end-of-the-road-for-some-features) to learn how the *Java Endorsed Standards Override Mechanism* is not supported in Java 9.

Read about the Override Mechanism on the Tomcat documentation [page on classloaders](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/class-loader-howto.html), in the section on XML parsers.

For alternatives, see the Question, [*How do you replace endorsed directory in Java 9?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46419496/how-do-you-replace-endorsed-directory-in-java-9)

You may need to switch to a later version of Tomcat to run with Java 9. I’m not clear on which Tomcat versions are yet compatible. You’ll need to do some research for news as we are still in the early days of Java 9.

I do know from my own experience that [Tomcat 9.0.2 beta](https://tomcat.apache.org/download-90.cgi) runs on Java 9.0.1 on macOS Sierra with [Vaadin](http://www.Vaadin.com/) 8.2.