# java.endorsed.dirs="" is no longer supported. IntelliJ 2019.3

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jvm, java-11

I am getting

> `JVMJ9VM148E java.endorsed.dirs="" is no longer supported. The endorsed-standards override mechanism is only supported via upgradable modules.
>   Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
>   Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.`

When trying to run a Java 11 program in IntelliJ 2019.3
This started happening after I updated my IntelliJ.

I have found this question on StackOverflow,: [How do you replace endorsed directory in Java 9?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46419496/how-do-you-replace-endorsed-directory-in-java-9)

And also this: form IntelliJ, https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360000615010-IntelliJ-is-adding-a-no-longer-supported-Djava-endorsed-dirs-JDK-9-parameter-on-Gradle-runs-which-results-in-failure

but none apply to my situation.

Does anyone know ho I can solve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: When do you get this error, when building or when running? If you search the project for `java.endorsed.dirs`, does it find anything? Do you have environment variables set that may override Java options with `java.endorsed.dirs`?

Comment: Was this resolved? I just started to have the same issue today.

Comment: It was fixed it was something stupid like the correct directory was not marked as root. now I don't remember to be honest. But it was something silly and not related to the error message I was receiving at all. :/