# IntelliJ Idea Cannot run java program

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I'm using IntelliJ Idea running on windows 10 as my IDE in creating Java programs. I tried to run a simple `System.out.println("test")` and it errors out like this:

```
Abnormal build process termination: 

C:\Users\Me\.sdkman\candidates\java\current\bin\java.exe -Xmx700m -Djava.awt.headless=true -Djava.endorsed.dirs=\"\" -Dcompile.parallel=false -Drebuild.on.dependency.change=true -Djdt.compiler.useSingleThread=true -Daether.connector.resumeDownloads=false -Dio.netty.initialSeedUniquifier=-6869199051656113394 -Dfile.encoding=windows-1252 -Duser.language=en -Duser.country=PH -Didea.paths.selector=IdeaIC2021.2 "-Didea.home.path=E:/Intellij/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2021.2.3" -Didea.config.path=C:/Users/Lourence/AppData/Roaming/JetBrains/IdeaIC2021.2 -Didea.plugins.path=C:/Users/Lourence/AppData/Roaming/JetBrains/IdeaIC2021.2/plugins -Djps.log.dir=C:/Users/Lourence/AppData/Local/JetBrains/IdeaIC2021.2/log/build-log "-Djps.fallback.jdk.home=E:/Intellij/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2021.2.3/jbr" -Djps.fallback.jdk.version=11.0.12 -Dio.netty.noUnsafe=true -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:/Users/Lourence/AppData/Local/JetBrains/IdeaIC2021.2/compile-server/primitivetypeschallenge_ac95c73c/_temp_ -Djps.backward.ref.index.builder=true -Dkotlin.incremental.compilation=true -Dkotlin.incremental.compilation.js=true -Dkotlin.daemon.enabled -Dkotlin.daemon.client.alive.path=\"C:\Users\Lourence\AppData\Local\Temp\kotlin-idea-10685239370109816991-is-running\" -Dtmh.instrument.annotations=true -Dtmh.generate.line.numbers=true -classpath "E:/Intellij/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2021.2.3/plugins/java/lib/jps-launcher.jar;C:/Users/Lourence/.sdkman/candidates/java/current/lib/tools.jar" org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.Launcher "E:/Intellij/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2021.2.3/lib/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8.jar;E:/Intellij/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2021.2.3/lib/jna-platform.jar;E:/Intellij/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2021.2.3/lib/annotations.jar;E:/Intellij/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2021.2.3/lib/util.jar;E:/Intellij/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2021.2.3/plugins/java/lib/aether-dependency-resolver.jar;E:/Intellij/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2021.2.3/lib/jps-model.jar;E:/Intellij/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2021.2.3/plugins/java/lib/maven-resolver-transport-http-1.3.3.jar;E:/Intellij/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2021.2.3/lib/forms_rt.jar;E:/Intellij/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2021.2.3/lib/3rd-party.jar;E:/Intellij/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2021.2.3/lib/platform-api.jar;E:/Intellij/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2021.2.3/plugins/java/lib/maven-resolver-connector-basic-1.3.3.jar;E:/Intellij/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2021.2.3/plugins/java/lib/jps-javac-extension-1.jar;E:/Intellij/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2021.2.3/plugins/java/lib/jps-builders-6.jar;E:/Intellij/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2021.2.3/lib/jna.jar;E:/Intellij/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2021.2.3/lib/protobuf-java-3.15.8.jar;E:/Intellij/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2021.2.3/plugins/java/lib/javac2.jar;E:/Intellij/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2021.2.3/plugins/java/lib/maven-resolver-transport-file-1.3.3.jar;E:/Intellij/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2021.2.3/lib/slf4j.jar;E:/Intellij/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2021.2.3/lib/idea_rt.jar;E:/Intellij/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2021.2.3/plugins/java/lib/jps-builders.jar;E:/Intellij/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2021.2.3/plugins/Kotlin/lib/kotlin-reflect.jar;E:/Intellij/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2021.2.3/plugins/Kotlin/lib/kotlin-plugin.jar;E:/Intellij/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2021.2.3/plugins/uiDesigner/lib/jps/java-guiForms-jps.jar;E:/Intellij/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2021.2.3/plugins/ant/lib/ant-jps.jar;E:/Intellij/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2021.2.3/plugins/eclipse/lib/eclipse-jps.jar;E:/Intellij/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2021.2.3/plugins/eclipse/lib/eclipse-common.jar;E:/Intellij/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2021.2.3/plugins/IntelliLang/lib/java-langInjection-jps.jar;E:/Intellij/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2021.2.3/plugins/Groovy/lib/groovy-jps.jar;E:/Intellij/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2021.2.3/plugins/Groovy/lib/groovy-constants-rt.jar;E:/Intellij/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2021.2.3/plugins/maven/lib/maven-jps.jar;E:/Intellij/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2021.2.3/plugins/gradle-java/lib/gradle-jps.jar;E:/Intellij/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2021.2.3/plugins/Kotlin/lib/jps/kotlin-jps-plugin.jar;E:/Intellij/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2021.2.3/plugins/Kotlin/lib/kotlin-jps-common.jar;E:/Intellij/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2021.2.3/plugins/Kotlin/lib/kotlin-common.jar;E:/Intellij/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2021.2.3/plugins/space/lib/space-java-jps.jar;E:/Intellij/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2021.2.3/plugins/devkit/lib/devkit-jps.jar;E:/Intellij/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2021.2.3/plugins/javaFX/lib/javaFX-jps.jar;E:/Intellij/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2021.2.3/plugins/javaFX/lib/javaFX-common.jar" org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildMain 127.0.0.1 52715 64406674-5475-4e21-88d9-5dfcad243b68 C:/Users/Lourence/AppData/Local/JetBrains/IdeaIC2021.2/compile-server
JVMJ9VM148E java.endorsed.dirs="" is no longer supported. The endorsed-standards override mechanism is only supported via upgradable modules.
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

It seems like something is deprecated, but I don't know what it is.

I'm using sdkman for my java versions. Currently using the java version `AdoptOpenJDK 11.0.11.j9`

Comment: There’s this that might be relevant : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46419496/how-do-you-replace-endorsed-directory-in-java-9

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you replace endorsed directory in Java 9?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46419496/how-do-you-replace-endorsed-directory-in-java-9)

Comment: When do you get this error, when building or when running? If you search the project for java.endorsed.dirs, does it find anything? Do you have environment variables set that may override Java options with java.endorsed.dirs?